# List<Object> Remove Duplicates, override equals

Tags: java

I have list of object where I am trying to eliminate duplicate objects

Some how below code doesn't eliminate duplicates

MAIN CLASS

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Rule1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Fna fna = new Fna(1,"1","1");
        Fna fna1 = new Fna(1,"1","1");
        Fna fna2 = new Fna(2,"2","2");

        List<Fna> fnas = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Fna> fnas2 = new ArrayList<>();
        fnas.add(fna);
        fnas.add(fna1);
        fnas.add(fna2);

        System.out.println(removeDuplicates(fnas).toString());


        for(Fna obj1 : fnas){
            for(Fna obj2: fnas){
                if(obj1.equals(obj2)) fnas.remove(obj1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(fnas.toString());
    }
```

Java pojo

```
public class Fna {
    int ID;
    String name;
    String lname;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public Fna(int ID, String name, String lname) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.lname = lname;
    }


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj == null) return false;
    else if (obj instanceof Fna && getID() == ((Fna) obj).getID() && getName().equals(((Fna) obj).getName())
            && getLname().equals(((Fna) obj).getLname()))
    return true;

    else return false;
}
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Output

```
[Fna@0, Fna@0, Fna@0]
[Fna@0, Fna@0, Fna@0]
```

Comment: You're comparing strings (`lname`,`name`) with `==`; you need to use `equals()` for that.

Comment: Also, you should use the same fields in `hashCode()` as you're using in `equals()` (they should be consistent). Now the hash code of each instance is the same.

Comment: Your nested for loops are never going to work. First, trying to remove an element from a collection inside a foreach loop over that collection should throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Second, if removing elements worked, you’d remove *all* elements: for each `obj1`, at some point `obj2` will be the same object. If the object is equal to itself, it will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your second comparison inside equals  is getName equals to getLName.
2. You need to return true if all fields are equal and not false as written.
3. Use String.equals for strings comparison instead of equality by reference (==)

Comment: Upvotes ` Mick Mnemonic` pointed it right, as you as well. Leaving solved code in question to help other SO reference